Tableau to Power BI Report builder Migration
I have a functionality in Tableau where a specific column (like Index) is created using Table Calculation option , this similar calculation has to be migrated in Power BI Report builder by grouping two columns which is used as column grouping in SSRS matrix.
enter image description here
I need solution to implement this similar functionality in Power BI report builder. I already saw the new calculation field option in Power bI Desktop but in my case its Paginated Report.
